# Deploy two different ASP.NET applications to the same Azure VM with IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment

**WEBSITE 1**:  I had a single ASP.NET MVC site in Visual Studio online and was building and then releasing from the Visual Studio Online to that Virtual machine.

[image]

**WEBSITE 2**: I decided to create another Solution/Project in Visual Studio online and run it off the same Virtual Machine (with continuous integration, etc). As part of setting up Deployment Groups for that project, I wanted to add **the same** virtual machine as for project 1 (I believe I cannot share Deployment Groups between projects).

When I executed the VSTS Agent script for site 2 on the virtual machine, the first website's target went "offline", and the machine lit up in the SITE 2 Deployment Group, disappearing from SITE 1 Deployment Group.

There seems to be only one VSTS Agent that can be set up to receive website deployments:

[image]

**Question**: How can I set up the same virtual machine with IIS to receive deployments for two separate websites within the same VS Online account? Is there a way to set up multiple VSTS Agents on a Azure Virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to deploy multiple agents for VSTS in a machine. You can use steps below to achieve this in azure VM or any single machine, when setting up deployment groups.

1. Copy the target registration PowerShell script to a notepad. Then replace the

   $env:SystemDrive\'vstsagent'

with a local path of your preference for agent for example

```
'g:\vstsagentprojX'
```

This will make the agent installed for project X deployment group setup in g:\vstsagentprojX.

[image]

2. Replace

   --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME

in the script with project specific name for example

```
--agent chamindac.projx
```

[image]

3. Then register the agent for Project X deployment group and it will be configured in the specified folder,

[image]

and with a unique service name since you have provided a project specific name for agent.

[image]

Follow steps similar to the other project and change its PowerShell script to have the

```
$env:SystemDrive\'vstsagent'
```

replace with project specific path for local folder say

```
'g:\vstsagentprojQ'
```

Then change --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME to a project specific name such as

```
--agent chamindac.projq
```

Then run the script to create the deployment group agent for the second project.

[image]

This will create two agent services with unique names in the same machine.
[image]

You should have two targets in two team project deployment groups, online.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As ChamindaC said that you can update the script to setup a new deployment agent.

Another way is that you can configure it manually:

1. Download the agent (the same as build/release) agent `https://{your_account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_AgentPool`
2. Extract the zip file to a folder (e.g. `c:\myagent`)
3. Run command line as administrator and change context to (`cd c:\myagent`) that folder (step 2)
4. Run `.\config.cmd –deploymentgroup` command and specify arguments when it asking

On the other hand, you can use the same agent that WEBSITE 1 used.